# How to get the CSV from a visualization online?

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, developer-tools

I want to be able to get this visualization working locally on my machine :

http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/political_influence/index.html?source=d3js

I got the javascript, html and css files from the Resources tab in the developer tools (Rightclick + inspect element). But it wont run as I haven't got the csv files needed.

Can someone tell me if it's possible to get the csv files from the developer tools the same way i got the javascript html and css files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to devtools -> network. refresh your browser and type in csv in the filter box
example:
Request URL:http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/political_influence/data/Contributions_Senate.csv

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you look in "data.js", you'll see that there is a function called `fetchData` that pulls the data from a few different urls.

For example, the first one, `addStream("data/Candidates_House.csv"...`, is pulling from http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/political_influence/data/Candidates_House.csv